# How can I create a mongoose virtual field that lists the length of a subdocument?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a node.js REST api route which returns projects objects as json minus the tasks:

```
   exports.list = function(req, res) {
    return Project.find(null,'-tasks',null,function(err, projects) {
     if (!err) {
      return res.json(projects);
     } else {
      return res.send(err);
     }
    });
   };
```

This is intended to be used for navigation elements that list all projects but won't be needing the individual tasks (which number in the 100s). This works well but now I need to include a count of the number of tasks in the navigation so I added this to my model:

```
var ProjectSchema = Schema({
  name    : String,
  tasks : [{ 
    name : String,
    state   : String }]
},
{
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});

ProjectSchema.virtual("taskCount").get(function(){
    return this.tasks.length;
});
```

But I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

Because you're excluding `tasks`, the virtual property cannot check the `length` of the property (as it's not defined).

Either include `tasks`, or include the length as a precomputed value of your schema. You could just use `$inc` on the field to change the length as new items are added to the array of tasks (or just set it directly).

Comment: Do you mean you're excluding `tasks` in the virtual? How would you create the virtual so that it has access to `tasks.length`?

Comment: The original question excluded the `tasks` field, so `length` could not be checked.

Comment: @WiredPrairie could you please give an example of how the `$inc` would apply in this scenario.

Comment: @AP - please ask a new question. I'd rather not add details to a question that is nearly 2 years old.